# How to add sg.FileBrowse in menu PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, layout, menu, pysimplegui

```
 menu_def = [['F̲ile',
             ['N̲ew...' + ' ' * 30 + 'Alt+Insert', "Load Python file", "Load C̲onfiguration", '---',
              " Open Image...",
              ' O̲pen...' + ' ' * 28 + 'Ctrl+O',
              'Open R̲ecent', ["s"], '---', 'Save' + ' ' * 37 + 'Ctrl+S', 'Close Project',
              ' Settings' + ' ' * 23 + 'Ctrl+Alt+S', 'Ex̲it']
             ],
            ['E̲dit', ['⤺  U̲ndo' + ' ' * 28 + 'Ctrl+Z', '!⤻ R̲edo' + ' ' * 20 + 'Ctrl+Shift+Z',
                       '---', 'Cut' + ' ' * 35 + 'Ctrl+X', 'C̲opy' + ' ' * 32 + 'Ctrl+C',
                       'Paste' + ' ' * 31 + 'Ctrl+V', 'Delete' + ' ' * 30 + 'D̲elete',
                       'D̲uplicate Line' + ' ' * 19 + 'Ctrl+D']
             ],
            ['H̲elp', '&About...'], ]
```

What I want is to launch browse file when user click either New or load python and config file

Take a look at this screenshot

[img.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJkAJ.png)

Comment: `sg.FileBrowse` cannot be added into menu, should call `sg.popup_get_file` in your event loop if event generated when you click on item in menu.

Comment: Is there been a way to put popup in menu_def as in applications when we press open it open browse for file to opened

Comment: The solution already replied in my previous comment.

Comment: See the PySimpleGUI Demo Program - Demo_Menus.py - as per Jason's recommendation to call from event loop.